# Usage of nation names as teams

Tags: sport, nationality

Can I use Country's names in my online championship game to allow players to recruit themselves in for their favourite/geographical nation and play against other nations?

Cases:

1. Is it legal to schedule a match between say, **Czech Republic V Kazakhstan** **at 13:00 GST** where players play as teams against each other.
2. Is it legal to create a olympic style leaderboard where the medals per country will be counted and displayed.

Thanks.

Comment: I can't immediately think of any reason why not, but what jurisdiction are you &c &c

Comment: See [Can a Western democracy prevent private groups from using the country’s name/purporting to represent that country e.g. at the World Cup?](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/31681/can-a-western-democracy-prevent-private-groups-from-using-the-country-s-name-pur)

Answer (score 1):

It is up to each and every state to set the protection of their national symbols. But even if they do, enforcing this protection can be very complicated against non-citizens in foreign country. Basically, country like Kazakhstan can enact a law that prevents you from using their name, but if you do, there is nothing they can do to stop you.)

There are some special cases, like, if you pretend to be an embassy, but this is not your case.

As far as I am concerned, there is no law in the Czech republic regulating the use of the word "czech".